# ¿Por qué recibo este error? "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" - JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

¡Hola amigos!

¿Por qué recibo el error que se ve en la captura?

Estoy haciendo un juego por niveles en js con canvas y no sé qué he tocado que se me ha crasheado y recibo este error.

Se supone que estoy recorriendo un array y me paso de su longitud, pero el problema es que no encuentro el lugar donde corregir esto.

CÓDIGO HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Gamedev Canvas Workshop</title>
    <style>
        * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
        canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="500"></canvas>

<script>

function main () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var ballRadius = 20;
  var x = canvas.width/2;
  var y = canvas.height-30;
  var dx = 2;
  var dy = -2;
  var paddleHeight = 10;
  var paddleWidth = 200;
  var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
  var rightPressed = false;
  var leftPressed = false;
  var brickRowCount = 2;
  var brickColumnCount = 2;
  var brickWidth = 75;
  var brickHeight = 20;
  var brickPadding = 10;
  var brickOffsetTop = 50;
  var brickOffsetLeft = 160;
  var score = 0;
  var lifes = 5;
  var level = 1;
  var color = getRandomColor();
  var bricks = [];

  function startBricks() {
      for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
          for(r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
              bricks[c][r].status = 1;
          }
      }
  }

  function getRandomColor () {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;

/*********************************************************/

/*********************************************************/

alert ("PRESS ENTER TO PLAY!");

  for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
  }
      bricks[c] = [];
      for(r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
          bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };
      }
  }

  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);

  function keyDownHandler(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 39) {
          rightPressed = true;
      }
      else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
          leftPressed = true;
      }
  }
  function keyUpHandler(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 39) {
          rightPressed = false;
      }
      else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
          leftPressed = false;
      }
  }
  function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
      var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      if(relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
          paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth/2;
      }
  }

  function collisionDetection() {
      for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
          for(r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
              var b = bricks[c][r];
              if(b.status == 1) {
                  if(x > b.x && x < b.x+brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y+brickHeight) {
                      dy = -dy;
                      b.status = 0;
                      score++;
                      if(score == brickRowCount * brickColumnCount) {
                          switch (level) {
                            case 1:
                              alert("Level 1: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 2 aquí abajo.
                              level = 2;
                              dy = -2;
                              x = canvas.width/2;
                              y = canvas.height-30;
                              brickRowCount = 2;
                              brickColumnCount = 2;
                              brickWidth = 100;
                              brickHeight = 10;
                              brickPadding = 1;
                              paddleHeight = 10;
                              paddleWidth = 200;
                              brickOffsetTop = 50;
                              brickOffsetLeft = 140;
                              paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
                              color = getRandomColor();
                              break;
                            case 2:
                              alert("Level 2: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 3 aquí abajo.
                              level = 3;
                              dy = 5;
                              x = canvas.width/2;
                              y = canvas.height-30;
                              brickRowCount = 4;
                              brickColumnCount = 3;
                              brickWidth = 30;
                              brickHeight = 30;
                              brickPadding = 50;
                              paddleHeight = 10;
                              paddleWidth = 150;
                              brickOffsetTop = 30;
                              brickOffsetLeft = 100;
                              paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
                              color = getRandomColor();
                              break;
                            case 3:
                              alert("Level 3: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 4 aquí abajo.
                              level = 4;
                              dy = 5;
                              x = canvas.width/2;
                              y = canvas.height-30;
                              brickRowCount = 2;
                              brickColumnCount = 3;
                              brickWidth = 30;
                              brickHeight = 30;
                              brickPadding = 25;
                              paddleHeight = 10;
                              paddleWidth = 150;
                              brickOffsetTop = 100;
                              brickOffsetLeft = 200;
                              paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
                              color = getRandomColor();
                              break;
                            case 4:
                              alert("Level 4: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 5 aquí abajo.
                              level = 5;
                              dy = 15;
                              x = canvas.width/2;
                              y = canvas.height-30;
                              brickRowCount = 1;
                              brickColumnCount = 9;
                              brickWidth = 100;
                              brickHeight = 30;
                              brickPadding = 20;
                              paddleHeight = 10;
                              paddleWidth = 150;
                              brickOffsetTop = 50;
                              brickOffsetLeft = 200;
                              paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
                              color = getRandomColor();
                              alert ("REGARD: You obtain a free lifes!");
                              lifes ++;
                              break;
                            case 5:
                              alert("Level 5: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 6 aquí abajo.


                              break;
                            case 6:
                              alert("Level 6: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 7 aquí abajo.

                              break;
                            case 7:
                              alert("Level 7: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 8 aquí abajo.

                              break;
                            case 8:
                              alert("Level 8: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 9 aquí abajo.

                              break;
                            case 9:
                              alert("Level 9: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 10 aquí abajo.

                              break;
                            case 10:
                              alert("Level 10: PASSED");
                              // EL JUEGO YA HA TERMINADO.

                              break;
                            startBricks();
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }

  function drawBall() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
  }
  function drawPaddle() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height-paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
  }
  function drawBricks() {
      for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
          for(r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
              if(bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
                  var brickX = (r*(brickWidth+brickPadding))+brickOffsetLeft;
                  var brickY = (c*(brickHeight+brickPadding))+brickOffsetTop;
                  bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
                  bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
                  ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                  ctx.fillStyle = color;
                  ctx.fill();
                  ctx.closePath();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  function drawScore() {
      ctx.font = "16px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
      ctx.fillText("SCORE: " + score, 8, 20);
  }
  function drawLevel() {
      ctx.font = "16px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
      ctx.fillText("LEVEL: " + level, 210, 20);
  }
  function drawlifes() {
      ctx.font = "16px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
      ctx.fillText("LIFES: " + lifes, canvas.width - 65, 20);
  }

  function draw() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      drawBricks();//
      drawBall();//
      drawPaddle();
      drawScore();
      drawLevel();//
      drawlifes();
      collisionDetection();

      if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
          dx = -dx;
          ctx.fillStyle = color;
      }
      if(y + dy < ballRadius) {
          dy = -dy;
          ctx.fillStyle = color;
      }
      else if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius) {
          if(x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
              dy = -dy;
          }
          else {
              lifes--;
              if(!lifes) {
                  alert("GAME OVER");
                  document.location.reload();
              }
              else {
                  x = canvas.width/2;
                  y = canvas.height-30;
                  dx = 3;
                  dy = dy;
                  paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
              }
          }
      }

      if(rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width-paddleWidth) {
          paddleX += 7;
      }
      else if(leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
          paddleX -= 7;
      }

      x += dx;
      y += dy;
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }

  draw();
}
window.onload = main;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

CAPTURA DEL ERROR:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me preguntaba si alguien podría echarme una mano.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

¡Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que inicializar primero tu matriz `bricks` llamando a la funcion `startBricks()`.  Ademas necesitas inicializar cada array y objeto dentro de dicha funcion.  Quedaria asi:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Gamedev Canvas Workshop</title>
    <style>
        * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
        canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="500"></canvas>

<script>

function main () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var ballRadius = 20;
  var x = canvas.width/2;
  var y = canvas.height-30;
  var dx = 2;
  var dy = -2;
  var paddleHeight = 10;
  var paddleWidth = 200;
  var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
  var rightPressed = false;
  var leftPressed = false;
  var brickRowCount = 2;
  var brickColumnCount = 2;
  var brickWidth = 75;
  var brickHeight = 20;
  var brickPadding = 10;
  var brickOffsetTop = 50;
  var brickOffsetLeft = 160;
  var score = 0;
  var lifes = 5;
  var level = 1;
  var color = getRandomColor();
  var bricks = [];

  function startBricks() {
      for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
          bricks[c] = [];
          for(r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
              bricks[c][r] = {};
              bricks[c][r].status = 1;
          }
      }
  }

  function getRandomColor () {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;

/*********************************************************/

/*********************************************************/

alert ("PRESS ENTER TO PLAY!");

  for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
  }
      bricks[c] = [];
      for(r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
          bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };
      }
  }

  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);

  function keyDownHandler(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 39) {
          rightPressed = true;
      }
      else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
          leftPressed = true;
      }
  }
  function keyUpHandler(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 39) {
          rightPressed = false;
      }
      else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
          leftPressed = false;
      }
  }
  function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
      var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      if(relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
          paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth/2;
      }
  }

  function collisionDetection() {
      for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
          for(r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
              var b = bricks[c][r];
              if(b.status == 1) {
                  if(x > b.x && x < b.x+brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y+brickHeight) {
                      dy = -dy;
                      b.status = 0;
                      score++;
                      if(score == brickRowCount * brickColumnCount) {
                          switch (level) {
                            case 1:
                              alert("Level 1: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 2 aquí abajo.
                              level = 2;
                              dy = -2;
                              x = canvas.width/2;
                              y = canvas.height-30;
                              brickRowCount = 2;
                              brickColumnCount = 2;
                              brickWidth = 100;
                              brickHeight = 10;
                              brickPadding = 1;
                              paddleHeight = 10;
                              paddleWidth = 200;
                              brickOffsetTop = 50;
                              brickOffsetLeft = 140;
                              paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
                              color = getRandomColor();
                              break;
                            case 2:
                              alert("Level 2: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 3 aquí abajo.
                              level = 3;
                              dy = 5;
                              x = canvas.width/2;
                              y = canvas.height-30;
                              brickRowCount = 4;
                              brickColumnCount = 3;
                              brickWidth = 30;
                              brickHeight = 30;
                              brickPadding = 50;
                              paddleHeight = 10;
                              paddleWidth = 150;
                              brickOffsetTop = 30;
                              brickOffsetLeft = 100;
                              paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
                              color = getRandomColor();
                              break;
                            case 3:
                              alert("Level 3: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 4 aquí abajo.
                              level = 4;
                              dy = 5;
                              x = canvas.width/2;
                              y = canvas.height-30;
                              brickRowCount = 2;
                              brickColumnCount = 3;
                              brickWidth = 30;
                              brickHeight = 30;
                              brickPadding = 25;
                              paddleHeight = 10;
                              paddleWidth = 150;
                              brickOffsetTop = 100;
                              brickOffsetLeft = 200;
                              paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
                              color = getRandomColor();
                              break;
                            case 4:
                              alert("Level 4: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 5 aquí abajo.
                              level = 5;
                              dy = 15;
                              x = canvas.width/2;
                              y = canvas.height-30;
                              brickRowCount = 1;
                              brickColumnCount = 9;
                              brickWidth = 100;
                              brickHeight = 30;
                              brickPadding = 20;
                              paddleHeight = 10;
                              paddleWidth = 150;
                              brickOffsetTop = 50;
                              brickOffsetLeft = 200;
                              paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
                              color = getRandomColor();
                              alert ("REGARD: You obtain a free lifes!");
                              lifes ++;
                              break;
                            case 5:
                              alert("Level 5: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 6 aquí abajo.


                              break;
                            case 6:
                              alert("Level 6: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 7 aquí abajo.

                              break;
                            case 7:
                              alert("Level 7: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 8 aquí abajo.

                              break;
                            case 8:
                              alert("Level 8: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 9 aquí abajo.

                              break;
                            case 9:
                              alert("Level 9: PASSED");
                              // Preparar 10 aquí abajo.

                              break;
                            case 10:
                              alert("Level 10: PASSED");
                              // EL JUEGO YA HA TERMINADO.

                              break;
                            startBricks();
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }

  function drawBall() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
  }
  function drawPaddle() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height-paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
  }
  function drawBricks() {
      for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {          
          for(r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
              if(bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
                  var brickX = (r*(brickWidth+brickPadding))+brickOffsetLeft;
                  var brickY = (c*(brickHeight+brickPadding))+brickOffsetTop;
                  bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
                  bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
                  ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                  ctx.fillStyle = color;
                  ctx.fill();
                  ctx.closePath();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  function drawScore() {
      ctx.font = "16px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
      ctx.fillText("SCORE: " + score, 8, 20);
  }
  function drawLevel() {
      ctx.font = "16px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
      ctx.fillText("LEVEL: " + level, 210, 20);
  }
  function drawlifes() {
      ctx.font = "16px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
      ctx.fillText("LIFES: " + lifes, canvas.width - 65, 20);
  }

  function draw() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      startBricks();
      drawBricks();//
      drawBall();//
      drawPaddle();
      drawScore();
      drawLevel();//
      drawlifes();
      collisionDetection();

      if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
          dx = -dx;
          ctx.fillStyle = color;
      }
      if(y + dy < ballRadius) {
          dy = -dy;
          ctx.fillStyle = color;
      }
      else if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius) {
          if(x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
              dy = -dy;
          }
          else {
              lifes--;
              if(!lifes) {
                  alert("GAME OVER");
                  document.location.reload();
              }
              else {
                  x = canvas.width/2;
                  y = canvas.height-30;
                  dx = 3;
                  dy = dy;
                  paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
              }
          }
      }

      if(rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width-paddleWidth) {
          paddleX += 7;
      }
      else if(leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
          paddleX -= 7;
      }

      x += dx;
      y += dy;
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }

  draw();
}
window.onload = main;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder y solucionarme el error, lo que pasa que ahora al colisionar con los bloques, no me desaparecen.